# How to create a zip file with password using javascript on website?

Tags: javascript, file, password-protection, zip

I need to create a zip file with images and it would be password protected. All the process need to run on client site website. 
Language for use: Javascript.

Comment: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/ , it might help

Comment: Thanks, But it still not support password protection. Password protection is important to me.

Comment: Is nodejs also an option?

Comment: Only on NodeJS?